# How to prevent selection options to reset value after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, sql

```
<form action="mydtr" method="post">

<select id="periodname">
<?php foreach($period as $period): ?>

<option><?= $period['period']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Im looking for ways to prevent selection options to reset after i select and submit. thank you in advance for the help

Comment: you mean retaining user selection after form submission? just process the `$_POST` variable input after submitting it: `<option value="<?php echo $_POST['period']; ?>" <?php echo (!empty($_POST) && $_POST['period'] === $period['period']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $_POST['period']; ?></option>` use the `selected` attribute

Comment: when i replace my code with your given code my select options becomes empty

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you asking for but here you go.

```
<?php $period = array("period1", "period2", "period3", "period4"); ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<select id="periodname" name="periodname">
    <?php foreach($period as $period): ?>
        <option><?= $period; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input value="submit" type="submit"></form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php if(isset($_POST["periodname"])): echo "Form was submitted and we set that value of the select box to selected ".$_POST["periodname"];?>
<script>
    $( "#periodname option" ).each(function( index ) {
        var item = $(this).val();
      if(item == "<?php echo $_POST["periodname"]?>"){
          $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    });
</script>
<?endif;?>
```